# why Extracting Json in android giving an exception?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to extract json object values from a url which is giving a json array.i tried removing `Toast.makeText()` from the `doInBackgound()` method. But its crashing.

Please help. Code is as following:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        static ArrayList<Bitmap>bitmap=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> json= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        private static String url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=7b414d5858e1af7c06a9fb87a11ea64b";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new Background().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=7b414d5858e1af7c06a9fb87a11ea64b");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        class Background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
                JsonParser j=new JsonParser();
                JSONArray air=j.getJsonFrmUrl(url);

                for(int i=0;i<air.length();i++) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject c=air.getJSONObject(i);
                        String image="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + c.getString("backdrop_path");
                        String id=c.getString("id");
                        String title=c.getString("original_title");
                        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("backdrop_path", image);
                        map.put("id", id);
                        map.put("original_title", title);
                        json.add(map);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        bitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image).getContent()));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post a complete stack trace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: can you post your JsonParser code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put   `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in `doInBackground(String...strings)` mehod.

This method is to perform a computation on a background thread.

You can write `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`    in 
`onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method

as you are calling 
`new Background().execute("YOUR_URL");` from there. 
Everything related to your activities should be done on UI Threads.

The UIThread is the main thread of execution for your application. This is where most of your application code is run. All of your application components (Activities, Services, ContentProviders, BroadcastReceivers) are created in this thread, and any system calls to those components are performed in this thread.

For instance, let's say your application is a single Activity class. Then all of the lifecycle methods and most of your event handling code is run in this UIThread. These are methods like `onCreate`, `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onClick`, etc. Additionally, this is where all of the updates to the UI are made. Anything that causes the UI to be updated or changed HAS to happen on the UI thread.

> For your Reference [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

When you explicitly spawn a new thread to do work in the background, this code is not run on the UIThread. So what happens if this background thread needs to do something that changes the UI? This is what the `runOnUiThread` is for. Actually you're supposed to use a Handler (see the link below for more info on this). It provides these background threads the ability to execute code that can modify the UI. They do this by putting the UI-modifying code in a Runnable object and passing it to the `runOnUiThread` method.

[Worker Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

Answer (score 0):

Use `runOnUiThread` API for your Toast message display :

```
    try{
       // use this API to update UI from background thread, the below code will run on main UI thread
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
    } catch(Exception e){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve your problem:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(your json response goes here)
JSONArray jsonArrayResults = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayResults.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObjResult=jsonArrayResults.getJSONObject(i);
     boolean adult = jsonObjResult.getBoolean("adult"));
     String backdrop_path = jsonObjResult.getString("backdrop_path"));
     int id = jsonObjResult.getInt("id"));
     String original_title = jsonObjResult.getString("original_title"));
     .............
     .............
     Your remaining code to store values in HashMap
}
```