# Updating UI In Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine

I want to Update UI from background thread and if user wants to interact with UI while updating then the UI should not blocked by background thread.

Please Help me out.

Comment: You cannot update ui from a background thread. You need to provide more details as to what your doing probably the codes that are most relevant.

Comment: You can see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31578704/4961506)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using handlers to post UI updates from background thread. You can refer https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html for code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can update UI from backgorund thread
[runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //ui update stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use handler to serve this purpose.**

**A simple example:**
Create a class:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it from where you want to update the UI like this:

```
new Thread(new Task()).start();
```

Complete Example can be found [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/).

Or you can also go with different approach. Using runOnUiThread method will also allow you to achieve your expected result.

**Example:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.setText("#" + i);
                    }
                });
```